# How to test Class.forName() using testng/junit?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, testng

I would like to test the part Class.forName(REDSHIFT_JDBC_DRIVER) and check the exception part. Is there any way to do this ?

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(REDSHIFT_JDBC_DRIVER);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, redShfitProperties);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("error", e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Exception in getting connection", e);
        throw e;
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: What would you like to test? Are you trying to test if the class gets loaded (or) are you trying to test if there's an exception when the class loading fails.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question , I was looking to check the exception part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the class name in your class and then test with a name of a class that does not exist.

```
public class YourClass {

    private final String jdbcDriver;

    public YourClass() {
        this(REDSHIFT_JDBC_DRIVER);
    }

    YourClass(String jdbcDriver) {
        this.jdbcDriver = jdbcDriver;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        ...
        Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
        ...
    }
}
```

Your test may look like this:

```
@Test
public void fails_with_RuntimeException_when_driver_is_not_available() {
    YourClass instance = new YourClass("this.class.does.not.exist");
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> instance.getConnection(...))
        isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class);
}
```